# Conditional variance of power set

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability, variance

Conditional Variance is expressed as

Var(X|Y) = Var(X|$\sigma$(Y)).

And unconditional variance

Var(X) = Var(X|$\mathcal{F_0}$)

where $\mathcal{F_0}$ is the trivial information set.

Then is Var(X|$\mathcal{P(\Omega)}$)= $0$

regardless of how I put X as a random variable ?

Comment: No.  Why would it be?

Comment: I thought the sigma field contains all the information needed. Isn't it relevant?

Comment: I thought if Fa and Fb are information sets and Fa《Fb,      V(X|Fa) >=V(X|Fb)

Comment: Sorry for the notation. I'm writing on a subway

Answer (score 0):

Any random variable $X$ is measurable w.r.t. the power set. Hence $E(X^{2}|\mathcal P(\Omega))=X^{2}$ and $E(X|\mathcal P(\Omega))=X$ so the conditional variance is $X^{2}-X^{2}=0$. Intuitively any random variable is a constant when conditioned on the power set and constants have variance $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Then it's inducible that

Comment: Conditional variance based on bigger and informaion set is smaller than that of counterpart right?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to write in mathematical language right now